# Google service drive is not working

Tags: laravel-5, google-api-client, drive

I'm working on google api client integrated with **Laravel5.2** and I'm facing problem just to list different files content into my drive account.

The client seems to be ok with credientials and accessing the service as google is showing the request ok on the usage monitoring but I'm still getting nothing here is the code I use:

**Middleware:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $client_email = 'id@kribbean-wave.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
    $private_key = file_get_contents(base_path().'/resources/assets/kribbean-wave.p12');

    $scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

    $credentials = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        $scopes,
        $private_key
    );

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()){

        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
        $request->request->set('client',$client);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and the **Controller:**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('Google');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $client = $request->request->get('client');

        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $result = $service->files->listFiles();
        $list = $result->getItems();
        dd(json_encode($list));
        return view('index')->with('result',$list);
    }
}
```

The middleware is working as expected but `dd(json_encode($list));` is empty.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

To allow service account to access the files in my own Google Drive, I have to give permission to the email address of the service account. Once the permissions are setup correctly, the list gets populated with the files that the service account is allowed to access.